# How to release memory associated to each process in prallelized operations

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

i am performing prallelized operations on millions of objects stored in a list `self.__list`.each new invocation to the `run` reserves memory, and for the entire contents of `self.__list` the entire memory overflows and it is almost impossible to continue processing.
i would like to know, how can i release memory reserved by specific process. in other words, i would like to do something as shown in the below posed section "run", so that before the run method returns, it should free memory associated to the respective process.

is that possible?how

**code**:

```
with Pool(processes=127) as pool:
        for res in pool.map(func=self.run,iterable=self.__list,chunksize=self.__chunckSize):
            #code
            pass               
            
    pool.close()       
    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()
```

**run**:

```
 def run(self,params):
    #
    #
    #
    # how to free memory here
    return
```

Comment: when a `process` ends the `os` and the `garbage collector` are responsible of freeing the process memory

Comment: @OmerDagry thanks, in your opinion, what could be the reasone for such memory overflow please

Comment: there are a lot of possibilities, you can try using `del` and then the name of the variable

Comment: let me know if it helps or not, if not there are other options but they require an understanding of python garbage collector

Comment: @OmerDagry i tried to use del. but it did not help.

Comment: there are lots of places where you could be leaking memory, you'd need to give a more complete example that highlights where the issue is occurring.  e.g. is it the worker processes that are running out of memory, the master process that collects the results, or maybe something else?  also what OS / spawn method are you using, what data is shared between processes, what persists between invocations of each `run`...  lots of things could be happening and you've not given many details.  something like https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene might help if you're not sure what's going on